# How do I make a discord js bot that DM's a mentioned user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot that lets you use a "!dm" command. I'm trying to make it so whenever someone uses the "!dm" command, puts a user ID/mention of a user, and puts a message, it DMs the user/user ID mentioned. This is my code:

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Client();

const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN;

const PREFIX = '!';

bot.on('ready', () => {
 console.log('This bot is active!');
});

bot.on('message', (message) => {
 if (message.content === '!dm') {
  const taggedUser = message.mentions.users.first();
  const user = client.users.cache.get(taggedUser.username);
  user.send('test');
 }
});

bot.login(TOKEN);
```

Comment: You want to use `taggedUser.id`, not `.username`

Comment: still doesnt work.

Comment: `taggedUser.send(...)`

Comment: @Elitezen your code doesnt work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const target = message.mentions.users.first()
if(!target) return message.reply('You Didnt State the User you want to send the dm to')

const msgs = args[1]
if(!msgs) return message.reply('You Didnt State the Message you want to send the user')

if(message.attachments.size > 0){
    var Attachment = message.attachments.array();
    var OurAttachment = Attachment[0];
    const attachment = new MessageAttachment(OurAttachment.url);

    target.send(msgs);
    target.send(attachment);
    message.channel.send('Sent a Dm to ' + target.username)

  } else {
     target.send(msgs);
     message.reply('Sent a Dm to ' + target.username)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked :) [image](https://i.ibb.co/Qv63sck/Screenshot-2021-05-13-10-16-22-AM.png)

Comment: The only thing is It only sends 1 word. For example, If i did `!dm @FireyAPI hi this is a test`, it would only send `hi` in dms.

Comment: Never mind, I used `args.splice()` to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The collection `client.users.cache.get()` is mapped by id, so it should be `client.users.cache.get(taggedUser.id);`. However, a much bigger issue, you called your client `bot` not `client`, so that's why `client.users.cache.get()` isn't working. The full code should look like:

```js
bot.on('message', (message) => {
 if (message.content === '!dm') {
  const taggedUser = message.mentions.users.first();
  const user = bot.users.cache.get(taggedUser.id);
  user.send('test');
 }
});
```

Make sure you remember what you called your variables!